# Django , Apache , Nginx And Internet Explorer

Tags: django, apache, internet-explorer, nginx

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 VPS which I used to run my django app.

I use apache + mod_wsgi backend for serving dynamic contents and nginx as frontend for serving static files and medias.

But the problem here is, when I see my web template offline (outside of django) everything is ok even in Internet Explorer, but when I run my app on vps or in localhost (only apache or apache + nginx or django development server) all other browsers show my webapp very well but in Internet Explorer everything is garbled. CSS styles is not well and also js scripts.

Thank you.

When I load the Admin Panel of mywebsite in Internet Explorer, everything is correct, but in main website pages the problem remains.

My Admin Panel is **not** django admin app, I wrote my own admin panel. It shows correctly in IE, but main site does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `location /` has proxy_pass `/static/` will have too. So /static/demo.png will goes to proxy.

Use something like

```
location @proxy { 
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81; 
    proxy_redirect     off; 
}
```

and try to see a file is exist in /, if not proxy it.

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
```

Comment: 'proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;'   will cause problem try remove last / so it will be 'proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;' edited my post.

Comment: hi, i chande my configuration like your; nginx now serve static files correctly but when i try to see my web homepage at / that should be served by apache i encounter 403 Forbidden from nginx

Comment: Can you look error.log? or do yo have other pages work well? like /index?

Comment: hi friend, the problem was sold and now nginx and apache work wey well together but the problem with ie still remains. ie dos'ent show web pages correctly but the my admin pages shows well in ie, as i said above admin panel is not django but i writed my own

Comment: What is your problem with IE? I didn't understant? Do you have a example page?

Comment: i will give you a example page soon , my problem is that when i view my designed template in offline (not in django) mode it show correctly in ie and other browsers but when i run my app with django development server or apache + nginx webpages didn't show correctly in ie. and everything is garbled, of course my admin panel show correctly in ie

Comment: You can try open F12 developers tools in ie, then swtich to network, press start capturing, and see whats files giving 404 or 500 errors. If everything file, then look Console, but if you show the website to me, i will fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

By chance, are you accessing the server through Virtualbox? The shared virtualbox filesystem may be the problem. See about this issue at [nginx serves broken characters (nginx on linux as guest system in vbox)](https://serverfault.com/questions/401081/nginx-serves-broken-characters-nginx-on-linux-as-guest-system-in-vbox).

If you are "uploading" the files to the server using the shared file systems, try using FTP or SCP to transfer the files to the server instead.

Comment: the server is virtualizied and shared with the vmware. when i only use apache or django development server for serving statics but the problem is exist. i think that the contents of css and js files are not load correctly in internet explorer

Comment: i change the sendfile and gzip options to off on nginx but the problem is reamins.

Comment: hi ,thanks for answer. when i use django development server or apache on my pc the problem with ie is remains. but only when i browse template offline there is not problem with ie